# Camunda 7 graphql tomcat war deployment problem

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, camunda

I have checked out the code from https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-platform-7-graphql this. I am able to run it as a spring boot application. All the services of camunda along with camunda rest apis and graphql apis are working perfectly fine.

However we have a specific need of deploying the camunda as a war file on tomcat 8. I am able to deploy this as a war in tomcat and camunda web and rest apis are working perfectly fine.
however I am not able to get the graphql result.

As per the github documentation, I have configured the example app of graphql. Here is the application yml

```
`camunda.bpm:
  admin-user:
    id: demo
    password: demo
    firstName: demo
  filter:
    create: All tasks

spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: true
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
    web-application-type: servlet
graphql:
  servlet:
    mapping: /graphql
    enabled: true
    websocket:
      enabled: true
auth:
  Filter: NO `
```

This above url mapping works for the spirngboot jar deployment.
The below curl works in case of the jar deployment.

```
`curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/web_thymeleaf_war_war/graphql -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"query": "{ tasks { id,name } }"}'`
```

`But when I deploy this as a war, I am not able to access the graphql apis :

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/web_thymeleaf_war_war/graphql -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"query": "{ tasks { id,name } }"}'

{"timestamp":"2023-10-02T04:15:06.547+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"","path":"/web_thymeleaf_war_war/graphql"}`
```